# When do we use runResourceT when programming with Conduit

Tags: haskell

```
{-#LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings#-}
module Main where

import Conduit

main = (sourceRandomN 10 :: Producer IO Int) $$ printC
```

This works but for the following I need to add runResourceT. Why ?

```
{-#LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings#-}
module Main where

import Conduit

main = runResourceT (sourceDirectoryDeep False "/home/bjorn/dev"  $$ printC)
```

Comment: PS: Google only return results from the conduit package itself when i search for `sourceRandomN`. Does it mean that nobody uses the library ?

Comment: `sourceRandomN` is a very new function (in the past 2 months), I'm not surprised it doesn't have a lot of discussion. However, I [did write a blog post using it](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2014/03/monte-carlo-haskell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at [the ResourceT overview](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/resourcet) to understand the purpose of resourcet. The short answer is that it lets you safely acquire resources inside a continuation-based monad, where normally safe exception handling isn't possible.

With `sourceDirectoryDeep`, the issue is that we need to safely open and close directory streams, in such a way that if an exception is thrown during processing, all currently open handles get closed.